# How to configure npm and package.json in subdirectory Visual Studio 2019 v16.6?

Tags: reactjs, npm, visual-studio-2019

I have a `Visual Studio v16.6 .NET Core 3.1` app with an embedded `React/Typescript app`.

The `react` app code is located in the `/ClientApp` folder.
The `package.json` and `node_modules` are located within the `/ClientApp` (root folder).

- When this project was in `VSC2017`, any changes made to the `package.json` were automatically updated in the `node_modules` folder.
- In `VSC2019` when the `package.json` is in the root folder, the npm dependencies are listed and updated when `package.json` is updated.

However, in `VSC2019`, when `package.json` is located in the `/ClientApp` folder neither the `node_modules` nor the npm `dependencies` are updated.

**Question:**
Is there a way to configure `VSC2019` to look in the `/ClientApp` folder for `package.json` and update npm `dependencies` accordingly?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @galvin No. Manually run npm install via Powershell following package.json updates.